# How should I use regex to search and replace special characters in a url?

Tags: regex, python-2.7

Suppose I have a url="https://google.com/?q=cats" then how can I search "://" and "?" and replace them with spaces?

```
import re
url="https://google.com/?q=cats"
re.search("\w+",url) # what should I include in this pattern to detect (:// and ?)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should sort you out:

```
re.sub('://|\?', ' ', url)
#https google.com/ q=cats
```

Comment: This works but why re.match(":\/\/",url) is returning None?

Comment: `re.match()` always matches from the start of the string. Try `re.search()` (to find the first match) or (as the answer shows) `re.sub()` to actually search and replace.

Comment: Also, it's a good habit to always use raw strings for regexes. Here, it works also with a normal string, but regexes that contain tokens like `\b` will trip you up :)

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> re.sub(r'(://|\?)', ' ', url)
'https google.com/ q=cats'
```